# sed not working with variables

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I am trying to compile a large project that I downloaded from Internet and I have a custom script that runs configure, make and make install. The problem is that I want to pass some compatibility flags but the project uses libtool which doesn't recognize LDFLAGS and I have to find another way to pass my compatibility flags. So in my script after running configure I have code that looks like this:

```
COMPATFLAG="-gcc-name=/usr/local/gcc-4.2.1/bin/gcc"
sed -i "s/CC -shared/CC -shared ${COMPATFLAG}/g" libtool
```

`${COMPATFLAG}` may get different values depending on what platform is being compiled for so I cannot put it in clear text in the sed statement. The problem is that it doesn't work - I get an empty space instead of the value of `${COMPATFLAG}`. If I instead write `sed -i "s/CC -shared/CC -shared TEST/g" libtool` it adds the string "TEST" to the file. If I use single quotes I get the `${COMPATFLAG}` string and not the variable's value. If I try to export `${COMPATFLAG}` it still doesn't work. I don't know why it goes wrong. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `COMPATFLAG` does have forward slashes you should use a different regex delimiter in sed:

```
sed -i "s#CC -shared#& ${COMPATFLAG}#g" libtool
```

Also I have used `#` here in order to avoid repetition of matched string in replacement pattern.

Thanks to @JonathanLeffler for this tip, you can even use a control character as regex delimiter:

```
sed -i "s^GCC -shared^G& ${COMPATFLAG}^Gg" libtool
```

Type `^G` as `ctrl-V-G` in shell

Comment: Another trick is to use a control character (such as control-A or control-G) as the delimiter; `sed` doesn't mind, and the chances of a conflict with arguments is minuscule.

Comment: And even `$'\xFF'`: `D=$'\xFF'; sed -i "s${D}CC -shared${D}& ${COMPATFLAG}${D}g" libtool`

Answer (score 3):

You can use pipe `|` instead of `/` with a double quote. That works for the global variables that include `/`.

```
sed -e "s|CC -shared|CC -shared ${COMPATFLAG}|g" libtool
```